# Force Derived Class To Implement a Given Method

Tags: c++, winforms, inheritance, abstract

I have a WinForms form which has multiple TabControl tabs. I implement the functionality of the tab pages by adding a user control to each tab page. This enables me to separate the functionality into a class for each page, rather than face the issues of a huge Form class.

Additionally, I have defined a tab pages base class to provide common functionality and references to application parameters. Thus the inheritance is UserControl -> PagesBase -> MyPage1 (MyPage2, etc). Provided PagesBase is not abstract, this all works well. I can design the individual pages normally within VS2012.

However, I would like to force each page to implement a small (common) set of methods and properties. First thought was to use an abstract PagesBase class. Unfortunately the individual page designers in VS would not start, complaining that they needed to create an instance of PagesBase.

Next thought was to apply an interface to PagesBase. But this doesn't work because it forces PagesBase to define all the common methods, etc and they are then available to the derived MyPageN classes, without them having to define their own. Interface won't allow them to be defined as private in the base class.

So down to expecting anyone adding a page to derive directly from a common interface (but not being able to enforce this) or raising runtime exceptions if a page called a base class method it had not overridden (no compile-time warning).

Am I missing something obvious? Any ideas, please?

Comment: Have you tried pure virtual methods?

Comment: you could declare your methods in the PagesBase as virtual and inside throw an exception to get a run time exception in case a method is not overriden in the chile pages classes.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Yes he has:  That is what he tried when he said "use an abstract PagesBase class".  The problem is that the Visual Studio GUI designer wants to create a "PagesBase" object - and can't.

Comment: Run time error + code review.  Sorry, I don't think there's an easy way round this.

Answer (score 0):

Normally an abstract PagesBase class (with pure virtual functions) would be a good way to go, except it doesn't seem to play well with the forms designer (note that I don't know how the designer works).

What you could do is split up your class into two parts:

- Your PagesBase class would be a concrete class with no pure virtual functions.
- PagesBase would hold a pointer to a MyPageIntf.
- MyPageIntf would be an abstract class that defines your page interface.
- MyPage1, MyPage2, etc. would be derived from MyPageIntf.
- You would implement functions in PagesBase using the MyPageIntf interface.
- If the designer calls any of these functions (that you implemented using the MyPageIntf interface), then in order to prevent nullptr crashes, in your PagesBase constructor you need to set the MyPageIntf pointer to an object that provides some kind of a default implementation of the interface. When running the app (as opposed to running in the designer), you would replace it with a real implementation (that is, MyPage1 / MyPage2 / etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a default constructor (no parameters) to your PagesBase class? That may be what the Designer is expecting in order to render it.